# Tensorflow issue google colab ; tensorflow._api.v1.compat.v2' has no attribute '__internal__

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, google-colaboratory

Tensorflow issue  google colab :  module 'tensorflow._api.v1.compat.v2' has no attribute '**internal**'
I am running a MASK RCNN model on google colab With tensorflow 1.15 and keras 2.1.6 every thing work correctly but Today, I got this error:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tP73l.png)

Comment: I am getting the same error. Anyone else facing the same problem? Any solutions?

Comment: I haven't found a solution yet

Comment: solution :  !pip uninstall keras-nightly   ///  pip uninstall -y tensorflow //// !pip install h5py==2.10.0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the benefit of community providing solution here though it is presented in [Github](https://github.com/googlecolab/colabtools/issues/2044#issuecomment-849161550).

Recently `colab` was upgraded to `TF 2.5.0`, forcing an upgrade to `keras-nightly 2.5.0.dev2021032900`.

The recent change affecting you is the install of `keras-nightly`, which is incompatible with `!pip install` of non-nightly `keras`. Adding `!pip uninstall keras-nightly` before `import keras` makes the error go away.

From comments

> ```
>  !pip uninstall keras-nightly
>
>  !pip uninstall -y tensorflow
>
>  !pip install h5py==2.10.0
> ```
>
> Followed by fresh installation of  tensorflow and keras as per requirement
> has solved the problem (paraphrased from nada belhadjslimen)