# Keras YoloV3 in on Google Colab, AttributeError: module 'keras.backend' has no attribute 'control_flow_ops

Tags: tensorflow, keras, google-colaboratory, tf.keras, yolo

I used Roboflow provided [Keras YoloV3 implementation](https://models.roboflow.com/object-detection/yolov3-keras) to train my own dataset on Google Colab.
Tried to demo run and the AttributeError occurred.

**Failed Solution1: [Github Ticket](https://github.com/qqwweee/keras-yolo3/issues/685)**
Tried to change the K.control_flow_ops.while.. to tf.while... which did not work for my colab notebook.

**Error code:**

```
/content/keras-yolo3/yolo3/model.py in yolo_loss(args, anchors, num_classes, ignore_thresh, print_loss)
    392             ignore_mask = ignore_mask.write(b, K.cast(best_iou<ignore_thresh, K.dtype(true_box)))
    393             return b+1, ignore_mask
--> 394         _, ignore_mask = ts.while_loop(lambda b,*args: b<m, loop_body, [0, ignore_mask])
    395         ignore_mask = ignore_mask.stack()
    396         ignore_mask = K.expand_dims(ignore_mask, -1)

AttributeError: module 'keras.backend' has no attribute 'control_flow_ops'
```

I know there are existing issues due to Google Colab's constant update on pre-installed libraries.

**Original Google Colab library versions are as below.**

```
Python 3.7.11
Name: tensorflow
Version: 2.5.0
Summary: TensorFlow is an open source machine learning framework for everyone.
Home-page: https://www.tensorflow.org/
Author: Google Inc.
Author-email: packages@tensorflow.org
License: Apache 2.0
Location: /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages
Requires: numpy, wheel, termcolor, astunparse, opt-einsum, keras-nightly, flatbuffers, protobuf, typing-extensions, six, google-pasta, gast, tensorflow-estimator, keras-preprocessing, tensorboard, wrapt, h5py, grpcio, absl-py
Required-by: kapre
Name: Keras
Version: 2.4.3
Summary: Deep Learning for humans
Home-page: https://github.com/keras-team/keras
Author: Francois Chollet
Author-email: francois.chollet@gmail.com
License: MIT
Location: /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages
Requires: scipy, h5py, pyyaml, numpy
Required-by: keras-vis
Name: h5py
Version: 3.1.0
Summary: Read and write HDF5 files from Python
Home-page: http://www.h5py.org
Author: Andrew Collette
Author-email: andrew.collette@gmail.com
License: BSD
Location: /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages
Requires: numpy, cached-property
Required-by: tensorflow, Keras, keras-vis
```

I'd also followed [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67694895/module-tensorflow-api-v1-compat-v2-has-no-attribute-internal-google-col) and downgraded all libraries as [this response](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67732583/16577218). Also, I tried to downgrade TensorFlow using this alternative:

```
%tensorflow_version 1.x
```

Which did not solve the problem. Any help is truly appreciated.

Comment: can you share more of a stack trace of your error. I mean not just the line that triggered it but trace from the libs (tf,keras) where it actually failed...

Answer (score 0):

**Option 1**: You can downgrade Keras from 2.4.3 to 2.1 as per that repository requirement

**Option 2**: you can use `tf.while_loop` instead K.control_flow_ops.while_loop after `"import tensorflow as tf "`
Saw a typo error "ts" here instead of tf

```
 _, ignore_mask = ts.while_loop(lambda b,*args: b<m, loop_body, [0, ignore_mask])
```

Edited

```
 _, ignore_mask = tf.while_loop(lambda b,*args: b<m, loop_body, [0, ignore_mask])
```